# Converting an analog signal of varying maximum and minimum values to a series of pulses

Tags: led, transistors, infrared

I have a situation where I need to convert an analog waveform into a series of pulses. The generated signal will be coming from an IR LED/photo-transistor pair that will output a signal whose maximum and minimum value will depend on the person whose finger between the IR LED/photo-transistor pair because of varying values in systolic and diastolic values of blood pressure among humans. I can't use a Schmitt trigger because I can't define a specific value to be the threshold limit above which the output is a logic level HIGH, and I can't use a peak detector because it would simply hold the highest value of the waveform which was sensed. Can someone please make a recommendation that would help me resolve this issue? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you draw a picture of the waveform, and the pulses you'd like to convert it into?

Comment: @Rocketmagnet- This is a picture of the waveform we must convert to a series of pulses. The only difference is that the units of the y-axis would be in volts (http://bsamig.uku.fi/research/bloodpress.shtml)

Comment: @DBrown, Rocket was also wanting you to draw what output you were wanting. I actually consider that the more important step of the two steps.

Comment: Pulse oximeter, eh? Use a resettable peak detector, and reset it after some suitable fraction of the signal period. All of the commercial ones use DSP.

Comment: @Kortuk and Rocketmagnet - Page 3 of this link has a picture of the pulse waveform that I would want(http://www.emo.org.tr/ekler/a568a2aa8c19a31_ek.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably pulse count is the aim and exact pulse separations in a given cycle are not too important.

General method is to create a reference based on the short to medium term values and compare the instantaneous value with that. Many possible methods. eg

- Average value produced by a simple RC integrator will produce a DC level equal to the DC mean value. RC time constant should be at least a few pulse cycles. Feed that and instant signal to a comparator.

  Using a 2 or 4 pole Bessel low pass filter here can make a nicely smoother but responsive mean value. Much better than single RC passive smoothing as need not be so heavily "slugged" but variation much better removed.  Each pile pair can be an emitter follower and x R, 2 x C. Cheap and easy.

Unity gain amp in LH low pass filter cct can be an emitter follower.
Circuit below from [here](https://sound-au.com/articles/active-filters.htm) very useful looking filter page.

[image]

- R1 input comp_-
  C1 comp_- ground
  input to comp+
  output = pulses (maybe :-))

---

- Produce a say +ve peak detector with a value a diode drop or so below V+ and smoothed as above.

---

- ADC - track rate of change signal. Not when slope goes +/- and -/+ for more than X samples etc.

---

- As above but analog.
  Input to resistor to capacitor to ground.
  Capacitor will track Vin with delay.
  Place comparator +/- inputs across R so when Vin is charging cap in will be > Vcap and when Vin is discharging cap Vin will be discharging cap so polarity across resistor will swap.

---

Noise an issue.
Short term variations against trend need smoothing.

Analog PLL track.

CD4066 digital PLL track.

Answer (score 4):

You could sample the signal with a microcontroller ADC (or a programmable DSP chip) and do the job of "converting it to digital pulses" in software to suit your needs.

Comment: I can't, I have to use the micro-controller ADC to do something else and I have to use an analog circuit(requirements for an assignment). Good suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use a voltage to frequency converter, such as the [LM231](http://search.digikey.com/us/en/products/LM231N%2FNOPB/LM231N-ND/148121).

You can also build one using op-amps, such as the [circuit here](http://electroschematics.com/4791/voltage-to-frequency-converter-circuit/).

Do a Google seqrch for "voltage to frequency circuit".

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a PWM generator would solve your problem nicely.

See Figure 5.3 of [this site](http://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/blog.php?b=378). It will convert your analog waveform into a series of pulses where the pulse-width is proportional to the signal amplitude. You can see a good picture of the waveforms [here](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-cqf4D6pcd2A/Ta5EVuumL0I/AAAAAAAAAQU/Xrq0QqvUoH8/s1600/PWM+control+ne555.gif).

Just make sure your PWM frequency (see the expression for F in the circuit) is much higher than your signal frequency. In your case, the heart rate is not usually higher than about 3 Hz (= 180 bpm), so something like 100 Hz PWM frequency is more than adequate.